# US Voting precinct data

Tags: shapefile, data

I am looking for a source for data to determine voting precinct boundaries in the United States. My thought is that they might be on the Census website but under a name that doesn't make it obvious.

Does anyone have a working link (or set of instructions) that will allow me to find that information?

Comment: Err, for which country?

Comment: @BradHards USA.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at the [Harvard Election Data Archive](http://projects.iq.harvard.edu/eda), which is for the 2008 elections. Curiously the shape files don't come with a .prj file, but that can be fixed. Also, boundary files are not available for all the states, unfortunately.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the first example I checked (my own address), I found that the data was out of date.

Comment: Thanks, @Steve Horn for pointing this out. Yes, those are for 2008. I am adding it to my answer as another limitation.

Answer (score 3):

There is [a github repository that seeks to maintain up-to-date precinct shapefiles](https://github.com/aaron-strauss/precinct-shapefiles) by github user [aaron-strauss](https://github.com/aaron-strauss).

From the README:

> Voting Precinct Shapefiles in the United States
>
> This project aims to catalog as many shapefiles of precincts (in some
>   states "voting tabulation districts", or "election districts") across
>   the United States. The priority is to obtain current shapefiles,
>   namely more recent than 2010.

Note that the repo organizes data by state, and for some states it provides an external link to a shapefile rather than the shapefile itself.

Answer (score 2):

The [Election Geodata git repository](https://github.com/nvkelso/election-geodata) seems like a promising source.